# Program won't start before stop the program frist?

Tags: labview, nidaqmx, daq-mx

I'm a newbie using LabView for my project. So I'm developing a program that gathers data from sensors that attach in the DAQmx board and also a spectrometer from STS-VIS ocean optic. At the first developing, I combine both devices in one loop inside the same flat structure, but I got an error saying: "The application is not able to keep up with the hardware acquisition." I cannot get the data showing on the graph for both devices, but it was just fine if I run it separately. And I found the solution saying that I need to separate both devices in a different while loop process because it may have different buffer size (?). I did it and it worked that all the sensors are showing in each graph. But the weird thing is, I need to stop the program first at the first run, then run it again for the second time for getting the graph showing in the application. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong and give me a solution? Due to the project rule I cannot share my Vi here publicly, but if anyone interested to help, I'd like to share it personally. Thank you.

Comment: why its not working in the first run, debug it first.

Comment: probably the DAQ is configured wrong. Note that it must buffer sensor data because the computer cannot write as fast as the module can sample. Eg. if you sample 10kHz you should write only at 1kHz... Further if you have two separate DAQ-nodes make sure that one is master and the other is slave (so it samples on demand). | In general: please provide the code so that we are not forced to guess

Comment: If you cannot share your vi maybe you can reproduce a minimal example (the basic outline) as @max suggested. At the moment we can just guess what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing right thing but you have to understand how Data acquisition work in LabVIEW and hardware.

you can increase hardware buffer Programmatically using property node or try to read fast as possible then you dont need two separate loop.

[NI](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019KTeSAM&l=de-DE)

Answer (score -1):

I work currently with a NI DAQmx device too and became desprate using LabView because there is not good documentation and/or examples. Then I started to use Python which I found more intuitively. The only disadvantage is that the userinterface is not so easily generated, but for this one can use the QT Designer (open source programm avaiable online).